# Retry cancelled tasks

Tags: c#, performance, multithreading, asynchronous, extension-methods

I wrote an extension method for retrying tasks when cancelled.

Can speed, versatility, readability, or elegance be improved at all?

```
public static async Task<T> Try<T>(this Task<T> task, int retries)
{
    var i = 0;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            // if cancelled, it can be reused
            var copy = task;
            return await copy;
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
    } while (i++ < retries);
    return default(T);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Task is a reference type, so your **copy** will always be the same initial **task**, and when it is cancelled it will stay cancelled forever - see [Restart a completed task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791493/restart-a-completed-task).

You can use Func instead of a Task as the argument and create a new Task out of it in each iteration of the loop.

```
   public static async Task<T> Try<T>(this Func<T> func, int retries)
    {
        var i = 0;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                return await Task.Run(func);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }
        } while (i++ < retries);
        return default(T);
    }
```

Comment: Oooooooooooops.